# Volume generated by revolving the region bounded by $x^2 - y^2 = 9$ and $y=\pm4$ about the $y$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

The problem is to find the volume of the solid generated by
revolving the region bounded by
the curve $x^2 - y^2 = 9$ and the lines $y=\pm4$ about the $y$-axis,
using both  the disk/washer and cylindrical shell methods.

(Image of problem source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1lqn.png)

I've found the answer using the washer/disc method but I'm at a loss as to how to find it using the cylindrical shell method. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The disk method works very easily in this case because
the intersection of the line $y=3$ and your
region generates a single disk, and the disk
has the same formula for $y=1$ or $y=-3$ as for $y=3$.

Constructing the cylindrical shells is just a little more complicated,
but not too complicated if you break the problem down into simpler pieces.

Consider the line $x=1$, which generates an infinite cylinder when you
rotate it around the $y$ axis.
What is the intersection of $x=1$ with the region you described?
Does it also generate a cylinder?

What happens if you look at the line $x=4$ instead?

Not every integration problem is solved by integrating a single,
simple formula over a single interval.
Sometimes you have to do one integral over one interval and then
a different integral over another integral.
A cylindrical shell method could give you one formula when 
$a < x < b$ and a different formula when $c < x < d$.
In some cases it may even give you two or more cylindrical
shells at the same value of $x$ 
(but different ranges of $y$ coordinates, of course).

Disk methods can be complicated that way too even though this problem
wasn't complicated to solve with disks.
Rotating some other region around the $y$ axis you could have had
washers with concentric disks (or other washers) in their "holes"
for some values of $y$ and just disks (or washers) for other values of $y$.
It often helps to draw a graph of the region that you rotated and
see how various vertical or horizontal lines intersect it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but what is the integrand that I need to use in this case? At which interval should I split the integrals up?

Comment: Since the minimum positive value of $x$ on the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 9$ is $x=3$, I'd look at that as the possible end of one integration interval and the start of the next interval. It should be clearer if you have a graph of the function, like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-y%5E2%3D9